# Typescript Decorators to abstract E2E Test biolerplate

Tags: typescript, cucumber, decorator

I have the following cucumber test which works:

```
import {defineSupportCode} from 'cucumber';
import action from './helpers/action';
import check from './helpers/action';

defineSupportCode(({ Given, Then }) => {
    Given(/^I open the (url|site) "([^"]*)?"$/,action.openWebsite);
    Then(/^I expect that the title is( not)* "([^"]*)?"$/,check.title);
});
```

What would like to do is to create a class and annotate the class, and relevant methods, with a decorator to abstract the cucumber boilerplate away.

Here is the class I created with the boilerplate still embedded, but it works:

```
class checkSite {
    constructor(){
        defineSupportCode(({ Given, Then }) => {
            Given(/^I open the (url|site) "([^"]*)?"$/,this.openWebsite);
            Then(/^I expect that the title is( not)* "([^"]*)?"$/,this.title);
        });
    }

    public openWebsite(type: any, page: any) {
        return action.openWebsite(type, page);
    }

    public title(Case: any, Title: any){
        check.Title(Case, Title);
    }
}

let CheckSite = new checkSite();
```

Here is what I would like the class to look like:

```
@binding
class checkSite {
    @Given(/^I open the (url|site) "([^"]*)?"$/)
    public openWebsite(type: any, page: any) {
        return action.openWebsite(type, page);
    }

    @Then(/^I expect that the title is( not)* "([^"]*)?"$/)
    public title(Case: any, Title: any) {
        return check.Title(Case, Title);
    }
}

let CheckSite = new checkSite();
```

Here is the GIVEN decorator with some basic test code:

```
export function given(value: any) {
    return function(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>){
        // save a reference to the original method
        let originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            // pre
            console.log('The method args are: ' + JSON.stringify(args));

            // run and store the result
            let result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);

            // post
            console.log('The return value is: ' + result);

            // return the result of the original method
            return result;
        };

        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

I am able to read the value of the @Given and @Then parameters into the decorator functions. I am also able to adjust the particular method. Where I get stuck is how to abstract, using a class decorator, the defineSupportCode function currently in the constructor out of the constructor.

Any direction would be appreciated...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an working implementation.

Feature File:

```
Feature: Site test
    As a developer
    I want google site to have the correct title

    Background:
        Given I open the url "http://www.google.com"

    Scenario: Google
        Then I expect that the title is "Google"
```

Test:

```
import { Cucumber, Given, When } from '../decorator/decorator'
import action from '../helpers/action';
import check from '../helpers/check';

@Cucumber
class checkSite {
    @Given(/^I open the (url|site) "([^"]*)?"$/)
    public openWebsite() {
        return action.openWebsite;
    };

    @When(/^I expect that the title is( not)* "([^"]*)?"$/)
    public title() {
        return check.Title
    };
};

let CheckSite = new checkSite();
```

Decorators:

```
import {defineSupportCode} from 'cucumber';

export function Cucumber(target: Function){
    for (var member in target.prototype) {
        target.prototype[member]();
    }
}

export function Given(expression: any) {
    return function(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>){
        let assertion = descriptor.value();

        descriptor.value = () => 
            defineSupportCode(({ Given }) => {
                Given(expression,assertion);
            });

        return descriptor;
    }
}

export function When(value: any) {
    return function(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>){
        let assertion = descriptor.value();

        descriptor.value = () => 
            defineSupportCode(({ When }) => {
                When(value, assertion);
            });

        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

Feel free to point out any possible improvements.